# Different results between a mex file and C file

Tags: c, matlab, visual-studio-2012, matrix, mex

I have a MATLAB code in which a computationally expensive part was converted into a C mex file. The mex file is:

```
/* Copyright Henrik Stewenius*/

/*************************************************
  Indata  : 9x4 matrix 
  Data out: 10x20 matrix   
*************************************************/
#include "mex.h"
#include <math.h>


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
/*nlhs    number of expected mxArrays.
  plhs    pointer to an array of NULL pointers.
  nrhs    number of input mxArrays.
  prhs    pointer to an array of input mxArrays.    */
{
  double *EE, *A;
  double e00,e01,e02,e03,e04,e05,e06,e07,e08;
  double e10,e11,e12,e13,e14,e15,e16,e17,e18;
  double e20,e21,e22,e23,e24,e25,e26,e27,e28;
  double e30,e31,e32,e33,e34,e35,e36,e37,e38;

  double e002,e012,e022,e032,e042,e052,e062,e072,e082;
  double e102,e112,e122,e132,e142,e152,e162,e172,e182;
  double e202,e212,e222,e232,e242,e252,e262,e272,e282;
  double e302,e312,e322,e332,e342,e352,e362,e372,e382;

  double e003,e013,e023,e033,e043,e053,e063,e073,e083;
  double e103,e113,e123,e133,e143,e153,e163,e173,e183;
  double e203,e213,e223,e233,e243,e253,e263,e273,e283;
  double e303,e313,e323,e333,e343,e353,e363,e373,e383;

  if(nrhs != 1  )     mexErrMsgTxt("EE (10*4)\n");
  EE = mxGetPr( prhs[0] )  ;
  plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(10 ,20  , mxREAL);
  A  = mxGetPr( plhs[0]);


e00 = EE[0*9 + 0 ];
e10 = EE[1*9 + 0 ];
e20 = EE[2*9 + 0 ];
e30 = EE[3*9 + 0 ];
e01 = EE[0*9 + 1 ];
e11 = EE[1*9 + 1 ];
e21 = EE[2*9 + 1 ];
e31 = EE[3*9 + 1 ];
e02 = EE[0*9 + 2 ];
e12 = EE[1*9 + 2 ];
e22 = EE[2*9 + 2 ];
e32 = EE[3*9 + 2 ];
e03 = EE[0*9 + 3 ];
e13 = EE[1*9 + 3 ];
e23 = EE[2*9 + 3 ];
e33 = EE[3*9 + 3 ];
e04 = EE[0*9 + 4 ];
e14 = EE[1*9 + 4 ];
e24 = EE[2*9 + 4 ];
e34 = EE[3*9 + 4 ];
e05 = EE[0*9 + 5 ];
e15 = EE[1*9 + 5 ];
e25 = EE[2*9 + 5 ];
e35 = EE[3*9 + 5 ];
e06 = EE[0*9 + 6 ];
e16 = EE[1*9 + 6 ];
e26 = EE[2*9 + 6 ];
e36 = EE[3*9 + 6 ];
e07 = EE[0*9 + 7 ];
e17 = EE[1*9 + 7 ];
e27 = EE[2*9 + 7 ];
e37 = EE[3*9 + 7 ];
e08 = EE[0*9 + 8 ];
e18 = EE[1*9 + 8 ];
e28 = EE[2*9 + 8 ];
e38 = EE[3*9 + 8 ];


e002 =e00*e00;
e102 =e10*e10;
e202 =e20*e20;
e302 =e30*e30;
e012 =e01*e01;
e112 =e11*e11;
e212 =e21*e21;
e312 =e31*e31;
e022 =e02*e02;
e122 =e12*e12;
e222 =e22*e22;
e322 =e32*e32;
e032 =e03*e03;
e132 =e13*e13;
e232 =e23*e23;
e332 =e33*e33;
e042 =e04*e04;
e142 =e14*e14;
e242 =e24*e24;
e342 =e34*e34;
e052 =e05*e05;
e152 =e15*e15;
e252 =e25*e25;
e352 =e35*e35;
e062 =e06*e06;
e162 =e16*e16;
e262 =e26*e26;
e362 =e36*e36;
e072 =e07*e07;
e172 =e17*e17;
e272 =e27*e27;
e372 =e37*e37;
e082 =e08*e08;
e182 =e18*e18;
e282 =e28*e28;
e382 =e38*e38;

e003 =e00*e00*e00;
e103 =e10*e10*e10;
e203 =e20*e20*e20;
e303 =e30*e30*e30;
e013 =e01*e01*e01;
e113 =e11*e11*e11;
e213 =e21*e21*e21;
e313 =e31*e31*e31;
e023 =e02*e02*e02;
e123 =e12*e12*e12;
e223 =e22*e22*e22;
e323 =e32*e32*e32;
e033 =e03*e03*e03;
e133 =e13*e13*e13;
e233 =e23*e23*e23;
e333 =e33*e33*e33;
e043 =e04*e04*e04;
e143 =e14*e14*e14;
e243 =e24*e24*e24;
e343 =e34*e34*e34;
e053 =e05*e05*e05;
e153 =e15*e15*e15;
e253 =e25*e25*e25;
e353 =e35*e35*e35;
e063 =e06*e06*e06;
e163 =e16*e16*e16;
e263 =e26*e26*e26;
e363 =e36*e36*e36;
e073 =e07*e07*e07;
e173 =e17*e17*e17;
e273 =e27*e27*e27;
e373 =e37*e37*e37;
e083 =e08*e08*e08;
e183 =e18*e18*e18;
e283 =e28*e28*e28;
e383 =e38*e38*e38;


A[0 + 10*0]=0.5*e003+0.5*e00*e012+0.5*e00*e022+0.5*e00*e032+e03*e01*e04+e03*e02*e05+0.5*e00*e062+e06*e01*e07+e06*e02*e08-0.5*e00*e042-0.5*e00*e052-0.5*e00*e072-0.5*e00*e082;
A[0 + 10*1]=e00*e11*e01+e00*e12*e02+e03*e00*e13+e03*e11*e04+e03*e01*e14+e03*e12*e05+e03*e02*e15+e13*e01*e04+e13*e02*e05+e06*e00*e16+1.5*e10*e002+0.5*e10*e012+0.5*e10*e022+0.5*e10*e062-0.5*e10*e042-0.5*e10*e052-0.5*e10*e072+0.5*e10*e032+e06*e11*e07+e06*e01*e17+e06*e12*e08+e06*e02*e18+e16*e01*e07+e16*e02*e08-e00*e14*e04-e00*e17*e07-e00*e15*e05-e00*e18*e08-0.5*e10*e082;
A[0 + 10*2]=e16*e02*e18+e03*e12*e15+e10*e11*e01+e10*e12*e02+e03*e10*e13+e03*e11*e14+e13*e11*e04+e13*e01*e14+e13*e12*e05+e13*e02*e15+e06*e10*e16+e06*e12*e18+e06*e11*e17+e16*e11*e07+e16*e01*e17+e16*e12*e08-e10*e14*e04-e10*e17*e07-e10*e15*e05-e10*e18*e08+1.5*e00*e102+0.5*e00*e122+0.5*e00*e112+0.5*e00*e132+0.5*e00*e162-0.5*e00*e152-0.5*e00*e172-0.5*e00*e182-0.5*e00*e142;
A[0 + 10*3]=0.5*e103+0.5*e10*e122+0.5*e10*e112+0.5*e10*e132+e13*e12*e15+e13*e11*e14+0.5*e10*e162+e16*e12*e18+e16*e11*e17-0.5*e10*e152-0.5*e10*e172-0.5*e10*e182-0.5*e10*e142;
A[0 + 10*4]=-e00*e28*e08-e00*e25*e05-e00*e27*e07-e00*e24*e04+e26*e02*e08+e26*e01*e07+e06*e02*e28+e06*e22*e08+e06*e01*e27+e06*e21*e07+e23*e02*e05+e23*e01*e04+e03*e02*e25+e03*e22*e05+e03*e01*e24+e03*e21*e04+e00*e22*e02+e00*e21*e01-0.5*e20*e082-0.5*e20*e052-0.5*e20*e072-0.5*e20*e042+e06*e00*e26+0.5*e20*e062+e03*e00*e23+0.5*e20*e022+1.5*e20*e002+0.5*e20*e032+0.5*e20*e012;
A[0 + 10*5]=-e10*e24*e04-e10*e27*e07-e10*e25*e05-e10*e28*e08-e20*e14*e04-e20*e17*e07-e20*e15*e05-e20*e18*e08-e00*e24*e14-e00*e25*e15-e00*e27*e17-e00*e28*e18+e06*e21*e17+e06*e22*e18+e06*e12*e28+e16*e00*e26+e16*e21*e07+e16*e01*e27+e16*e22*e08+e16*e02*e28+e26*e11*e07+e26*e01*e17+e26*e12*e08+e26*e02*e18+e06*e11*e27+e23*e11*e04+e23*e01*e14+e23*e12*e05+e23*e02*e15+e06*e20*e16+e06*e10*e26+e03*e21*e14+e03*e22*e15+e03*e12*e25+e13*e00*e23+e13*e21*e04+e13*e01*e24+e13*e22*e05+e13*e02*e25+e03*e11*e24+e03*e20*e13+e03*e10*e23+e00*e21*e11+3*e00*e20*e10+e00*e22*e12+e20*e12*e02+e20*e11*e01+e10*e22*e02+e10*e21*e01;
A[0 + 10*6]=-0.5*e20*e152+e26*e11*e17-e10*e24*e14-e10*e25*e15-e10*e27*e17-e10*e28*e18+0.5*e20*e162+e13*e10*e23+e13*e22*e15+e23*e12*e15+e23*e11*e14+e16*e10*e26+e16*e21*e17+e16*e11*e27+e16*e22*e18+e16*e12*e28+e26*e12*e18+e13*e12*e25+0.5*e20*e132+1.5*e20*e102+0.5*e20*e122+0.5*e20*e112+e10*e21*e11+e10*e22*e12+e13*e11*e24-0.5*e20*e172-0.5*e20*e182-0.5*e20*e142+e13*e21*e14;
A[0 + 10*7]=-e20*e25*e05-e20*e28*e08-0.5*e00*e272-0.5*e00*e282-0.5*e00*e242+0.5*e00*e262-0.5*e00*e252+e06*e20*e26+0.5*e00*e232+e06*e22*e28+e06*e21*e27+e26*e21*e07+e26*e01*e27+e26*e22*e08+e26*e02*e28-e20*e24*e04-e20*e27*e07+e03*e20*e23+e03*e22*e25+e03*e21*e24+e23*e21*e04+e23*e01*e24+e23*e22*e05+e23*e02*e25+e20*e21*e01+e20*e22*e02+1.5*e00*e202+0.5*e00*e222+0.5*e00*e212;
A[0 + 10*8]=e23*e21*e14+e23*e11*e24+e23*e22*e15+e23*e12*e25+e16*e20*e26+e16*e22*e28+e16*e21*e27+e26*e21*e17+e26*e11*e27+e26*e22*e18+e26*e12*e28+1.5*e10*e202+0.5*e10*e222+0.5*e10*e212+0.5*e10*e232+e20*e21*e11+e20*e22*e12+e13*e20*e23+e13*e22*e25+e13*e21*e24-e20*e24*e14-e20*e25*e15-e20*e27*e17-e20*e28*e18-0.5*e10*e272-0.5*e10*e282-0.5*e10*e242-0.5*e10*e252+0.5*e10*e262;
A[0 + 10*9]=0.5*e203+0.5*e20*e222+0.5*e20*e212+0.5*e20*e232+e23*e22*e25+e23*e21*e24+0.5*e20*e262+e26*e22*e28+e26*e21*e27-0.5*e20*e252-0.5*e20*e272-0.5*e20*e282-0.5*e20*e242;
A[0 + 10*10]=e06*e32*e08-0.5*e30*e082-0.5*e30*e042-0.5*e30*e052-0.5*e30*e072+0.5*e30*e012+0.5*e30*e022+0.5*e30*e032+0.5*e30*e062+1.5*e30*e002+e00*e31*e01+e00*e32*e02+e03*e31*e04+e03*e01*e34+e03*e32*e05+e03*e02*e35+e33*e01*e04+e33*e02*e05+e06*e00*e36+e06*e31*e07+e06*e01*e37+e06*e02*e38+e36*e01*e07+e36*e02*e08-e00*e34*e04-e00*e37*e07-e00*e35*e05-e00*e38*e08+e03*e00*e33;
A[0 + 10*11]=e06*e30*e16+e03*e30*e13+e16*e31*e07+e06*e10*e36-e10*e37*e07+3*e00*e30*e10+e00*e32*e12-e00*e38*e18-e10*e34*e04-e10*e35*e05-e10*e38*e08-e30*e14*e04-e30*e17*e07-e30*e15*e05-e30*e18*e08+e00*e31*e11+e10*e31*e01+e10*e32*e02+e30*e11*e01+e30*e12*e02+e03*e10*e33-e00*e34*e14-e00*e35*e15-e00*e37*e17+e03*e31*e14+e03*e11*e34+e03*e32*e15+e03*e12*e35+e13*e00*e33+e13*e31*e04+e13*e01*e34+e13*e32*e05+e13*e02*e35+e33*e11*e04+e33*e01*e14+e33*e12*e05+e33*e02*e15+e06*e31*e17+e06*e11*e37+e06*e32*e18+e06*e12*e38+e16*e00*e36+e16*e01*e37+e16*e32*e08+e16*e02*e38+e36*e11*e07+e36*e01*e17+e36*e12*e08+e36*e02*e18;
A[0 + 10*12]=e13*e10*e33+e33*e11*e14+e16*e10*e36+e16*e31*e17+e16*e11*e37+e16*e32*e18+e16*e12*e38+e36*e12*e18+e36*e11*e17-e10*e34*e14-e10*e35*e15-e10*e37*e17-e10*e38*e18+e10*e31*e11+e10*e32*e12+e13*e31*e14+e13*e11*e34+e13*e32*e15+e13*e12*e35+e33*e12*e15+1.5*e30*e102+0.5*e30*e122+0.5*e30*e112+0.5*e30*e132+0.5*e30*e162-0.5*e30*e152-0.5*e30*e172-0.5*e30*e182-0.5*e30*e142;
A[0 + 10*13]=e00*e32*e22+3*e00*e30*e20+e00*e31*e21+e20*e31*e01+e20*e32*e02+e30*e21*e01+e30*e22*e02+e03*e20*e33+e03*e32*e25+e03*e22*e35+e03*e31*e24+e03*e21*e34+e23*e00*e33+e23*e31*e04+e23*e01*e34+e23*e32*e05+e23*e02*e35+e33*e21*e04+e33*e01*e24+e33*e22*e05+e33*e02*e25+e06*e30*e26+e06*e20*e36+e06*e32*e28+e06*e22*e38+e06*e31*e27+e06*e21*e37+e26*e00*e36+e26*e31*e07+e03*e30*e23+e26*e01*e37+e26*e32*e08+e26*e02*e38+e36*e21*e07+e36*e01*e27+e36*e22*e08+e36*e02*e28-e00*e35*e25-e00*e37*e27-e00*e38*e28-e00*e34*e24-e20*e34*e04-e20*e37*e07-e20*e35*e05-e20*e38*e08-e30*e24*e04-e30*e27*e07-e30*e25*e05-e30*e28*e08;
A[0 + 10*14]=e16*e30*e26+e13*e21*e34+3*e10*e30*e20+e10*e32*e22+e10*e31*e21+e20*e31*e11+e20*e32*e12+e30*e21*e11+e30*e22*e12+e13*e30*e23+e13*e20*e33+e13*e32*e25+e13*e22*e35+e13*e31*e24+e23*e10*e33+e23*e31*e14+e23*e11*e34+e23*e32*e15+e23*e12*e35+e33*e21*e14+e33*e11*e24+e33*e22*e15+e33*e12*e25+e16*e20*e36+e16*e32*e28+e16*e22*e38+e16*e31*e27+e16*e21*e37+e26*e10*e36+e26*e31*e17+e26*e11*e37+e26*e32*e18+e26*e12*e38+e36*e21*e17+e36*e11*e27+e36*e22*e18+e36*e12*e28-e10*e35*e25-e10*e37*e27-e10*e38*e28-e10*e34*e24-e20*e34*e14-e20*e35*e15-e20*e37*e17-e20*e38*e18-e30*e24*e14-e30*e25*e15-e30*e27*e17-e30*e28*e18;
A[0 + 10*15]=-e20*e34*e24+0.5*e30*e262-0.5*e30*e252-0.5*e30*e272-0.5*e30*e282-0.5*e30*e242+1.5*e30*e202+0.5*e30*e222+0.5*e30*e212+0.5*e30*e232+e20*e32*e22+e20*e31*e21+e23*e20*e33+e23*e32*e25+e23*e22*e35+e23*e31*e24+e23*e21*e34+e33*e22*e25+e33*e21*e24+e26*e20*e36+e26*e32*e28+e26*e22*e38+e26*e31*e27+e26*e21*e37+e36*e22*e28+e36*e21*e27-e20*e35*e25-e20*e37*e27-e20*e38*e28;
A[0 + 10*16]=0.5*e00*e322+e30*e32*e02+e30*e31*e01+1.5*e00*e302+0.5*e00*e312+e03*e32*e35+e33*e31*e04+e33*e01*e34+e33*e32*e05+e33*e02*e35+e06*e30*e36+e06*e31*e37+e06*e32*e38+e36*e31*e07+e36*e01*e37+e36*e32*e08+e36*e02*e38-e30*e34*e04-e30*e37*e07-e30*e35*e05-e30*e38*e08+0.5*e00*e332+0.5*e00*e362-0.5*e00*e382-0.5*e00*e352-0.5*e00*e342-0.5*e00*e372+e03*e30*e33+e03*e31*e34;
A[0 + 10*17]=0.5*e10*e362-0.5*e10*e382-0.5*e10*e352-0.5*e10*e342-0.5*e10*e372+e36*e31*e17+e36*e11*e37+e36*e32*e18+e36*e12*e38-e30*e34*e14-e30*e35*e15-e30*e37*e17-e30*e38*e18+1.5*e10*e302+0.5*e10*e312+0.5*e10*e322+0.5*e10*e332+e30*e31*e11+e30*e32*e12+e13*e30*e33+e13*e31*e34+e13*e32*e35+e33*e31*e14+e33*e11*e34+e33*e32*e15+e33*e12*e35+e16*e30*e36+e16*e31*e37+e16*e32*e38;
A[0 + 10*18]=e33*e31*e24+e33*e21*e34+e26*e30*e36+e26*e31*e37+e26*e32*e38+e36*e32*e28+e36*e22*e38+e36*e31*e27+e36*e21*e37-e30*e35*e25-e30*e37*e27-e30*e38*e28-e30*e34*e24+e33*e22*e35+1.5*e20*e302+0.5*e20*e312+0.5*e20*e322+0.5*e20*e332+0.5*e20*e362-0.5*e20*e382-0.5*e20*e352-0.5*e20*e342-0.5*e20*e372+e30*e32*e22+e30*e31*e21+e23*e30*e33+e23*e31*e34+e23*e32*e35+e33*e32*e25;
A[0 + 10*19]=0.5*e303+0.5*e30*e312+0.5*e30*e322+0.5*e30*e332+e33*e31*e34+e33*e32*e35+0.5*e30*e362+e36*e31*e37+e36*e32*e38-0.5*e30*e382-0.5*e30*e352-0.5*e30*e342-0.5*e30*e372;
A[1 + 10*0]=e00*e01*e04+0.5*e002*e03+e00*e02*e05+0.5*e033+0.5*e03*e042+0.5*e03*e052+0.5*e03*e062+e06*e04*e07+e06*e05*e08-0.5*e03*e012-0.5*e03*e072-0.5*e03*e022-0.5*e03*e082;
A[1 + 10*1]=e03*e14*e04+e10*e01*e04+e16*e05*e08+e00*e10*e03+e00*e11*e04+e00*e01*e14+e00*e12*e05+e00*e02*e15+e10*e02*e05+e03*e15*e05+e06*e03*e16+e06*e14*e07+e06*e04*e17+e06*e15*e08+e06*e05*e18+0.5*e002*e13+1.5*e13*e032+0.5*e13*e042+0.5*e13*e052+0.5*e13*e062-0.5*e13*e012-0.5*e13*e072-0.5*e13*e022-0.5*e13*e082+e16*e04*e07-e03*e12*e02-e03*e11*e01-e03*e17*e07-e03*e18*e08;
A[1 + 10*2]=-e13*e11*e01+e00*e10*e13+e00*e12*e15+e00*e11*e14+e10*e11*e04+e10*e01*e14+e10*e12*e05+e10*e02*e15+e13*e14*e04+e13*e15*e05+e06*e13*e16+e06*e15*e18+e06*e14*e17+e16*e14*e07+e16*e04*e17+e16*e15*e08+e16*e05*e18-e13*e12*e02-e13*e17*e07-e13*e18*e08+0.5*e102*e03+1.5*e03*e132+0.5*e03*e152+0.5*e03*e142+0.5*e03*e162-0.5*e03*e112-0.5*e03*e172-0.5*e03*e122-0.5*e03*e182;
A[1 + 10*3]=0.5*e102*e13+e10*e11*e14+e10*e12*e15+0.5*e133+0.5*e13*e152+0.5*e13*e142+0.5*e13*e162+e16*e15*e18+e16*e14*e17-0.5*e13*e112-0.5*e13*e122-0.5*e13*e172-0.5*e13*e182;
A[1 + 10*4]=-e03*e28*e08-e03*e27*e07-e03*e21*e01-e03*e22*e02+e26*e05*e08+e26*e04*e07+e06*e05*e28+e06*e25*e08+e06*e04*e27+e06*e24*e07+e03*e25*e05+e03*e24*e04+e20*e02*e05+e20*e01*e04+e00*e02*e25+e00*e22*e05+e00*e01*e24+e00*e21*e04+e00*e20*e03-0.5*e23*e072-0.5*e23*e082-0.5*e23*e022-0.5*e23*e012+e06*e03*e26+0.5*e23*e052+0.5*e23*e062+1.5*e23*e032+0.5*e23*e042+0.5*e002*e23;
A[1 + 10*5]=e00*e21*e14+e00*e11*e24+e00*e10*e23+e00*e22*e15+e00*e12*e25+e20*e12*e05+e20*e01*e14+e20*e11*e04+e00*e20*e13+e10*e02*e25+e10*e22*e05+e10*e01*e24+e10*e21*e04+e10*e20*e03+e23*e15*e05+e23*e14*e04+e13*e25*e05+e13*e24*e04+e03*e24*e14+e03*e25*e15+3*e03*e23*e13+e20*e02*e15+e16*e03*e26+e06*e14*e27-e23*e18*e08+e06*e24*e17+e06*e15*e28+e06*e25*e18+e06*e13*e26+e06*e23*e16+e26*e04*e17+e26*e14*e07+e16*e05*e28+e16*e25*e08+e16*e04*e27+e16*e24*e07-e03*e22*e12-e03*e21*e11+e26*e05*e18+e26*e15*e08-e03*e27*e17-e03*e28*e18-e13*e22*e02-e13*e28*e08-e13*e27*e07-e13*e21*e01-e23*e17*e07-e23*e11*e01-e23*e12*e02;
A[1 + 10*6]=-0.5*e23*e182-0.5*e23*e172-0.5*e23*e112-0.5*e23*e122-e13*e22*e12-e13*e27*e17-e13*e28*e18+e26*e15*e18+e26*e14*e17-e13*e21*e11+e20*e12*e15+e13*e25*e15+e13*e24*e14+e16*e13*e26+e16*e25*e18+e16*e15*e28+e16*e24*e17+e16*e14*e27+1.5*e23*e132+0.5*e23*e152+0.5*e23*e142+0.5*e23*e162+e10*e20*e13+e10*e21*e14+e10*e11*e24+e10*e22*e15+e10*e12*e25+e20*e11*e14+0.5*e102*e23;
A[1 + 10*7]=e26*e04*e27+e00*e22*e25-e23*e28*e08+0.5*e03*e262-0.5*e03*e212-0.5*e03*e272-0.5*e03*e222-0.5*e03*e282+e23*e24*e04+e23*e25*e05+0.5*e202*e03+e06*e23*e26+e06*e24*e27+e06*e25*e28+e26*e24*e07+e26*e25*e08+e26*e05*e28-e23*e22*e02-e23*e21*e01-e23*e27*e07+e00*e20*e23+e00*e21*e24+e20*e21*e04+e20*e01*e24+e20*e22*e05+e20*e02*e25+1.5*e03*e232+0.5*e03*e242+0.5*e03*e252;
A[1 + 10*8]=e20*e11*e24-0.5*e13*e212-0.5*e13*e272-0.5*e13*e222-0.5*e13*e282-e23*e27*e17-e23*e28*e18+e26*e25*e18+e26*e24*e17+e26*e14*e27-e23*e21*e11-e23*e22*e12+e26*e15*e28+e23*e25*e15+e23*e24*e14+e16*e23*e26+e16*e24*e27+e16*e25*e28+0.5*e13*e262+e20*e21*e14+e20*e22*e15+e20*e12*e25+0.5*e13*e242+0.5*e13*e252+0.5*e202*e13+1.5*e13*e232+e10*e20*e23+e10*e22*e25+e10*e21*e24;
A[1 + 10*9]=0.5*e202*e23+e20*e22*e25+e20*e21*e24+0.5*e233+0.5*e23*e242+0.5*e23*e252+0.5*e23*e262+e26*e24*e27+e26*e25*e28-0.5*e23*e212-0.5*e23*e272-0.5*e23*e222-0.5*e23*e282;
A[1 + 10*10]=e00*e30*e03+0.5*e33*e062-0.5*e33*e012-0.5*e33*e022-0.5*e33*e072+e03*e35*e05+e06*e03*e36+e06*e34*e07+e06*e04*e37+e06*e35*e08+e06*e05*e38+e36*e04*e07+e36*e05*e08-e03*e32*e02-e03*e31*e01-e03*e37*e07+e00*e31*e04+e00*e01*e34+e00*e32*e05+e00*e02*e35+e30*e01*e04+e30*e02*e05+e03*e34*e04-e03*e38*e08+0.5*e002*e33+1.5*e33*e032+0.5*e33*e042+0.5*e33*e052-0.5*e33*e082;
A[1 + 10*11]=e06*e35*e18+e06*e33*e16+e00*e30*e13+e00*e10*e33+e00*e31*e14+e00*e11*e34+e00*e32*e15+e00*e12*e35+e10*e30*e03-e33*e17*e07-e33*e18*e08+e10*e31*e04+e10*e01*e34+e10*e32*e05+e10*e02*e35+e30*e11*e04+e30*e01*e14+e30*e12*e05+e30*e02*e15+3*e03*e33*e13+e03*e35*e15+e03*e34*e14+e13*e34*e04+e13*e35*e05+e33*e14*e04+e33*e15*e05+e06*e13*e36+e06*e15*e38+e06*e34*e17+e06*e14*e37+e16*e03*e36+e16*e34*e07+e16*e04*e37+e16*e35*e08+e16*e05*e38+e36*e14*e07+e36*e04*e17+e36*e15*e08+e36*e05*e18-e03*e31*e11-e03*e32*e12-e03*e37*e17-e03*e38*e18-e13*e32*e02-e13*e31*e01-e13*e37*e07-e13*e38*e08-e33*e12*e02-e33*e11*e01;
A[1 + 10*12]=e16*e13*e36+e10*e11*e34+0.5*e33*e152+0.5*e33*e142+0.5*e33*e162-0.5*e33*e112-0.5*e33*e122-0.5*e33*e172-0.5*e33*e182+0.5*e102*e33+1.5*e33*e132+e10*e30*e13+e10*e31*e14+e10*e32*e15+e10*e12*e35+e30*e11*e14+e30*e12*e15+e13*e35*e15+e13*e34*e14+e16*e35*e18+e16*e15*e38+e16*e34*e17+e16*e14*e37+e36*e15*e18+e36*e14*e17-e13*e31*e11-e13*e32*e12-e13*e37*e17-e13*e38*e18;
A[1 + 10*13]=e06*e35*e28+e36*e04*e27+e00*e20*e33+e00*e30*e23+3*e03*e33*e23+e03*e34*e24+e03*e35*e25+e23*e34*e04+e23*e35*e05+e33*e24*e04+e33*e25*e05+e06*e33*e26+e06*e23*e36+e06*e34*e27+e06*e24*e37+e06*e25*e38+e26*e03*e36+e26*e34*e07+e26*e04*e37+e26*e35*e08+e26*e05*e38+e36*e24*e07+e36*e25*e08+e36*e05*e28-e03*e31*e21-e03*e37*e27-e03*e32*e22-e03*e38*e28-e23*e32*e02-e23*e31*e01-e23*e37*e07-e23*e38*e08-e33*e22*e02-e33*e21*e01-e33*e27*e07-e33*e28*e08+e00*e32*e25+e00*e22*e35+e00*e31*e24+e00*e21*e34+e20*e30*e03+e20*e31*e04+e20*e01*e34+e20*e32*e05+e20*e02*e35+e30*e21*e04+e30*e01*e24+e30*e22*e05+e30*e02*e25;
A[1 + 10*14]=e10*e30*e23+e10*e20*e33+e10*e22*e35+e10*e32*e25+e10*e31*e24+e10*e21*e34+e20*e30*e13+e20*e31*e14+e20*e11*e34+e20*e32*e15+e20*e12*e35+e30*e21*e14+e30*e11*e24+e30*e22*e15+e30*e12*e25+3*e13*e33*e23+e13*e34*e24+e13*e35*e25+e23*e35*e15+e23*e34*e14+e33*e25*e15+e33*e24*e14+e16*e33*e26+e16*e23*e36+e16*e34*e27+e16*e24*e37+e16*e35*e28+e16*e25*e38+e26*e13*e36+e26*e35*e18+e26*e15*e38+e26*e34*e17+e26*e14*e37+e36*e25*e18+e36*e15*e28+e36*e24*e17+e36*e14*e27-e13*e31*e21-e13*e37*e27-e13*e32*e22-e13*e38*e28-e23*e31*e11-e23*e32*e12-e23*e37*e17-e23*e38*e18-e33*e21*e11-e33*e22*e12-e33*e27*e17-e33*e28*e18;
A[1 + 10*15]=-0.5*e33*e212-0.5*e33*e272-0.5*e33*e222-0.5*e33*e282+e26*e23*e36+e20*e30*e23+e20*e32*e25+e20*e22*e35+e20*e31*e24+e20*e21*e34+e30*e22*e25+e30*e21*e24+e23*e34*e24+e23*e35*e25+e26*e34*e27+e26*e24*e37+e26*e35*e28+e26*e25*e38+e36*e24*e27+e36*e25*e28-e23*e31*e21-e23*e37*e27-e23*e32*e22-e23*e38*e28+0.5*e202*e33+1.5*e33*e232+0.5*e33*e242+0.5*e33*e252+0.5*e33*e262;
A[1 + 10*16]=e33*e35*e05+e30*e32*e05+0.5*e03*e362+0.5*e302*e03+1.5*e03*e332+0.5*e03*e352+0.5*e03*e342+e00*e30*e33+e00*e31*e34+e00*e32*e35+e30*e31*e04+e30*e01*e34+e30*e02*e35+e33*e34*e04+e06*e33*e36+e06*e35*e38+e06*e34*e37+e36*e34*e07+e36*e04*e37+e36*e35*e08+e36*e05*e38-e33*e32*e02-e33*e31*e01-e33*e37*e07-e33*e38*e08-0.5*e03*e322-0.5*e03*e382-0.5*e03*e312-0.5*e03*e372;
A[1 + 10*17]=-e33*e31*e11-e33*e32*e12-e33*e38*e18+e30*e11*e34+e30*e32*e15+e30*e12*e35+e33*e35*e15+e33*e34*e14+e16*e33*e36+e16*e35*e38+e16*e34*e37+e36*e35*e18+e36*e15*e38+e36*e34*e17+e36*e14*e37-e33*e37*e17+0.5*e302*e13+1.5*e13*e332+0.5*e13*e352+0.5*e13*e342+0.5*e13*e362-0.5*e13*e322-0.5*e13*e382-0.5*e13*e312-0.5*e13*e372+e10*e30*e33+e10*e31*e34+e10*e32*e35+e30*e31*e14;
A[1 + 10*18]=e36*e25*e38+0.5*e302*e23+1.5*e23*e332+0.5*e23*e352+0.5*e23*e342+0.5*e23*e362-0.5*e23*e322-0.5*e23*e382-0.5*e23*e312-0.5*e23*e372+e20*e30*e33+e20*e31*e34+e20*e32*e35+e30*e32*e25+e30*e22*e35+e30*e31*e24+e30*e21*e34+e33*e34*e24+e33*e35*e25+e26*e33*e36+e26*e35*e38+e26*e34*e37+e36*e34*e27+e36*e24*e37+e36*e35*e28-e33*e31*e21-e33*e37*e27-e33*e32*e22-e33*e38*e28;
A[1 + 10*19]=0.5*e302*e33+e30*e31*e34+e30*e32*e35+0.5*e333+0.5*e33*e352+0.5*e33*e342+0.5*e33*e362+e36*e35*e38+e36*e34*e37-0.5*e33*e322-0.5*e33*e382-0.5*e33*e312-0.5*e33*e372;
A[2 + 10*0]=0.5*e002*e06+e00*e01*e07+e00*e02*e08+0.5*e032*e06+e03*e04*e07+e03*e05*e08+0.5*e063+0.5*e06*e072+0.5*e06*e082-0.5*e06*e012-0.5*e06*e022-0.5*e06*e042-0.5*e06*e052;
A[2 + 10*1]=e00*e10*e06+0.5*e002*e16+0.5*e032*e16+1.5*e16*e062+0.5*e16*e072+0.5*e16*e082-0.5*e16*e012-0.5*e16*e022-0.5*e16*e042-0.5*e16*e052+e00*e11*e07+e00*e01*e17+e00*e12*e08+e00*e02*e18+e10*e01*e07+e10*e02*e08+e03*e13*e06+e03*e14*e07+e03*e04*e17+e03*e15*e08+e03*e05*e18+e13*e04*e07+e13*e05*e08+e06*e17*e07+e06*e18*e08-e06*e12*e02-e06*e11*e01-e06*e14*e04-e06*e15*e05;
A[2 + 10*2]=e13*e14*e07+0.5*e102*e06+e00*e10*e16+e00*e12*e18+e00*e11*e17+e10*e11*e07+e10*e01*e17+e10*e12*e08+e10*e02*e18+e03*e13*e16+e03*e15*e18+e03*e14*e17+e13*e04*e17+e13*e15*e08+e13*e05*e18+e16*e17*e07+e16*e18*e08-e16*e12*e02-e16*e11*e01-e16*e14*e04-e16*e15*e05+0.5*e132*e06+1.5*e06*e162+0.5*e06*e182+0.5*e06*e172-0.5*e06*e112-0.5*e06*e122-0.5*e06*e142-0.5*e06*e152;
A[2 + 10*3]=0.5*e102*e16+e10*e12*e18+e10*e11*e17+0.5*e132*e16+e13*e15*e18+e13*e14*e17+0.5*e163+0.5*e16*e182+0.5*e16*e172-0.5*e16*e112-0.5*e16*e122-0.5*e16*e142-0.5*e16*e152;
A[2 + 10*4]=e06*e27*e07+e23*e05*e08+e23*e04*e07+e03*e05*e28+e03*e25*e08+e03*e04*e27+e03*e24*e07+e20*e02*e08+e20*e01*e07+e00*e02*e28+e00*e22*e08+e00*e01*e27+e00*e21*e07+e00*e20*e06-e06*e25*e05-e06*e24*e04-e06*e21*e01-e06*e22*e02+e06*e28*e08-0.5*e26*e042-0.5*e26*e052-0.5*e26*e012-0.5*e26*e022+0.5*e26*e082+0.5*e26*e072+1.5*e26*e062+0.5*e002*e26+e03*e23*e06+0.5*e032*e26;
A[2 + 10*5]=e13*e05*e28+e00*e12*e28+e13*e25*e08+e13*e04*e27+e13*e24*e07+e13*e23*e06+e03*e14*e27+e03*e24*e17+e03*e15*e28+e03*e25*e18+e03*e13*e26+e03*e23*e16+e20*e02*e18+e20*e12*e08+e20*e01*e17+e20*e11*e07+e00*e21*e17+e10*e02*e28+e10*e22*e08+e10*e01*e27+e10*e21*e07+e10*e20*e06+e00*e11*e27-e26*e15*e05-e26*e14*e04-e26*e11*e01-e26*e12*e02-e16*e25*e05-e16*e24*e04-e16*e21*e01-e16*e22*e02-e06*e24*e14-e06*e22*e12-e06*e21*e11-e06*e25*e15+e00*e20*e16+e00*e22*e18+e00*e10*e26+e26*e18*e08+e26*e17*e07+e16*e28*e08+e16*e27*e07+e06*e27*e17+e06*e28*e18+3*e06*e26*e16+e23*e05*e18+e23*e15*e08+e23*e04*e17+e23*e14*e07;
A[2 + 10*6]=e10*e22*e18+0.5*e26*e182+0.5*e26*e172+e16*e28*e18+e16*e27*e17-e16*e25*e15-e16*e21*e11-e16*e22*e12+1.5*e26*e162+e13*e15*e28+e13*e24*e17+e13*e14*e27+e23*e15*e18+e23*e14*e17+e10*e12*e28+e10*e21*e17+e10*e11*e27+e20*e12*e18+e20*e11*e17+e13*e23*e16+e13*e25*e18+e10*e20*e16+0.5*e102*e26-0.5*e26*e122-0.5*e26*e142-0.5*e26*e152-e16*e24*e14-0.5*e26*e112+0.5*e132*e26;
A[2 + 10*7]=-0.5*e06*e212-0.5*e06*e252-0.5*e06*e242+0.5*e06*e272+0.5*e06*e282-0.5*e06*e222+e20*e02*e28+e03*e23*e26+e03*e24*e27+e03*e25*e28+e23*e24*e07+e23*e04*e27+e23*e25*e08+e23*e05*e28+e26*e28*e08-e26*e22*e02-e26*e21*e01-e26*e24*e04-e26*e25*e05+e26*e27*e07+e00*e20*e26+e00*e21*e27+e00*e22*e28+e20*e21*e07+e20*e01*e27+e20*e22*e08+0.5*e202*e06+0.5*e232*e06+1.5*e06*e262;
A[2 + 10*8]=-e26*e24*e14-0.5*e16*e212-0.5*e16*e252-0.5*e16*e242-e26*e25*e15-0.5*e16*e222-e26*e21*e11+e26*e28*e18+e26*e27*e17-e26*e22*e12+e23*e15*e28+e23*e24*e17+e23*e14*e27+0.5*e232*e16+1.5*e16*e262+0.5*e16*e272+0.5*e16*e282+e10*e20*e26+e10*e21*e27+e10*e22*e28+e20*e22*e18+e20*e12*e28+e20*e21*e17+e20*e11*e27+e13*e23*e26+e13*e24*e27+e13*e25*e28+e23*e25*e18+0.5*e202*e16;
A[2 + 10*9]=0.5*e202*e26+e20*e21*e27+e20*e22*e28+0.5*e232*e26+e23*e24*e27+e23*e25*e28+0.5*e263+0.5*e26*e272+0.5*e26*e282-0.5*e26*e222-0.5*e26*e212-0.5*e26*e252-0.5*e26*e242;
A[2 + 10*10]=e03*e34*e07+0.5*e032*e36+1.5*e36*e062+e03*e33*e06+e00*e31*e07+e00*e01*e37+e00*e32*e08+e00*e02*e38+e30*e01*e07+e30*e02*e08+e03*e04*e37+e03*e35*e08+e03*e05*e38+0.5*e002*e36-0.5*e36*e022-0.5*e36*e042-0.5*e36*e052+0.5*e36*e072+0.5*e36*e082-0.5*e36*e012+e33*e04*e07+e33*e05*e08+e06*e37*e07+e06*e38*e08-e06*e32*e02-e06*e31*e01-e06*e34*e04-e06*e35*e05+e00*e30*e06;
A[2 + 10*11]=e13*e33*e06+e13*e34*e07+e13*e04*e37+e13*e35*e08+e13*e05*e38+e33*e14*e07+e33*e04*e17+e33*e15*e08+e33*e05*e18+3*e06*e36*e16+e06*e38*e18+e06*e37*e17+e16*e37*e07+e16*e38*e08+e36*e17*e07+e36*e18*e08-e06*e35*e15-e06*e31*e11-e06*e32*e12+e00*e31*e17+e00*e11*e37+e10*e30*e06+e10*e31*e07+e10*e01*e37+e10*e32*e08+e10*e02*e38+e30*e11*e07+e30*e01*e17+e30*e12*e08+e30*e02*e18+e03*e33*e16+e03*e13*e36+e03*e35*e18+e03*e15*e38+e03*e34*e17+e03*e14*e37+e00*e30*e16+e00*e12*e38-e06*e34*e14-e16*e32*e02-e16*e31*e01-e16*e34*e04-e16*e35*e05-e36*e12*e02-e36*e11*e01-e36*e14*e04-e36*e15*e05+e00*e10*e36+e00*e32*e18;
A[2 + 10*12]=0.5*e36*e182+0.5*e36*e172-0.5*e36*e112-0.5*e36*e122-0.5*e36*e142-0.5*e36*e152+0.5*e102*e36+0.5*e132*e36+1.5*e36*e162+e10*e30*e16+e10*e32*e18+e10*e12*e38+e10*e31*e17+e10*e11*e37+e30*e12*e18+e30*e11*e17+e13*e33*e16+e13*e35*e18+e13*e15*e38+e13*e34*e17+e13*e14*e37+e33*e15*e18+e33*e14*e17+e16*e38*e18+e16*e37*e17-e16*e35*e15-e16*e31*e11-e16*e32*e12-e16*e34*e14;
A[2 + 10*13]=e00*e20*e36+e00*e31*e27+e00*e21*e37+e00*e32*e28+e00*e22*e38+e20*e30*e06+e20*e31*e07+e20*e01*e37+e20*e32*e08+e20*e02*e38+e30*e21*e07+e30*e01*e27+e30*e22*e08+e30*e02*e28+e03*e33*e26+e03*e23*e36+e03*e34*e27+e03*e24*e37+e03*e35*e28-e26*e31*e01-e26*e35*e05-e36*e22*e02-e36*e21*e01-e36*e24*e04-e36*e25*e05-e26*e34*e04+e03*e25*e38+e23*e34*e07+e23*e04*e37+e23*e35*e08+e23*e05*e38+e33*e24*e07+e33*e04*e27+e33*e25*e08+e33*e05*e28+3*e06*e36*e26+e06*e37*e27+e06*e38*e28+e26*e37*e07+e26*e38*e08+e36*e27*e07+e36*e28*e08-e06*e32*e22-e06*e31*e21-e06*e35*e25-e06*e34*e24-e26*e32*e02+e00*e30*e26+e23*e33*e06;
A[2 + 10*14]=e10*e30*e26+e10*e20*e36+e10*e31*e27+e10*e21*e37+e10*e32*e28+e10*e22*e38+e20*e30*e16+e20*e32*e18+e20*e12*e38+e20*e31*e17+e20*e11*e37+e30*e22*e18+e30*e12*e28+e30*e21*e17+e30*e11*e27+e13*e33*e26+e13*e23*e36+e13*e34*e27+e13*e24*e37+e13*e35*e28+e13*e25*e38+e23*e33*e16+e23*e35*e18+e23*e15*e38+e23*e34*e17+e23*e14*e37+e33*e25*e18+e33*e15*e28+e33*e24*e17+e33*e14*e27+3*e16*e36*e26+e16*e37*e27+e16*e38*e28+e26*e38*e18+e26*e37*e17+e36*e28*e18+e36*e27*e17-e16*e32*e22-e16*e31*e21-e16*e35*e25-e16*e34*e24-e26*e35*e15-e26*e31*e11-e26*e32*e12-e26*e34*e14-e36*e25*e15-e36*e21*e11-e36*e22*e12-e36*e24*e14;
A[2 + 10*15]=e33*e25*e28+e20*e30*e26+e20*e32*e28+e20*e31*e27+e20*e21*e37+e20*e22*e38+e30*e21*e27+e30*e22*e28+e23*e33*e26+e23*e34*e27+e23*e24*e37+e23*e35*e28+e23*e25*e38+e33*e24*e27+e26*e37*e27+e26*e38*e28-e26*e32*e22-e26*e31*e21-e26*e35*e25-e26*e34*e24+0.5*e202*e36+0.5*e232*e36+1.5*e36*e262+0.5*e36*e272+0.5*e36*e282-0.5*e36*e222-0.5*e36*e212-0.5*e36*e252-0.5*e36*e242;
A[2 + 10*16]=e00*e30*e36+e00*e32*e38+e00*e31*e37+e30*e31*e07+e30*e01*e37+e30*e32*e08+e30*e02*e38+e03*e33*e36-0.5*e06*e342+e03*e35*e38+e33*e34*e07+e33*e04*e37+e33*e35*e08+e33*e05*e38+e36*e37*e07+e36*e38*e08-e36*e32*e02-e36*e31*e01-e36*e34*e04-e36*e35*e05+e03*e34*e37+0.5*e302*e06+0.5*e332*e06+1.5*e06*e362+0.5*e06*e382+0.5*e06*e372-0.5*e06*e352-0.5*e06*e312-0.5*e06*e322;
A[2 + 10*17]=-e36*e35*e15+e10*e30*e36+0.5*e302*e16+0.5*e332*e16+1.5*e16*e362+0.5*e16*e382+0.5*e16*e372-0.5*e16*e352-0.5*e16*e312-0.5*e16*e322-0.5*e16*e342+e10*e32*e38+e10*e31*e37+e30*e32*e18+e30*e12*e38+e30*e31*e17+e30*e11*e37+e13*e33*e36+e13*e35*e38+e13*e34*e37+e33*e35*e18+e33*e15*e38+e33*e34*e17+e33*e14*e37+e36*e38*e18+e36*e37*e17-e36*e31*e11-e36*e32*e12-e36*e34*e14;
A[2 + 10*18]=-e36*e35*e25+e30*e32*e28+0.5*e302*e26+0.5*e332*e26+1.5*e26*e362+0.5*e26*e382+0.5*e26*e372-0.5*e26*e352-0.5*e26*e312-0.5*e26*e322-0.5*e26*e342+e20*e30*e36+e20*e32*e38+e20*e31*e37+e30*e31*e27+e30*e21*e37+e30*e22*e38+e23*e33*e36+e23*e35*e38+e23*e34*e37+e33*e34*e27+e33*e24*e37+e33*e35*e28+e33*e25*e38+e36*e37*e27+e36*e38*e28-e36*e32*e22-e36*e31*e21-e36*e34*e24;
A[2 + 10*19]=0.5*e302*e36+e30*e32*e38+e30*e31*e37+0.5*e332*e36+e33*e35*e38+e33*e34*e37+0.5*e363+0.5*e36*e382+0.5*e36*e372-0.5*e36*e352-0.5*e36*e312-0.5*e36*e322-0.5*e36*e342;

}
```

To call the same file from visual studio, I just ommitted:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <math.h>


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

and replaced it with:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
void  fivepoint_helper (float *A, float *E)
```

Where `E` is a `[9x4]` input matrix and `A` is a `[10*20]` output matrix ( I work with linear indexing of matrices).

The problem is that the same C file called from MATLAB as a mex file or visual studio as a C file gives very different results for the output matrix `A`

What is causing this difference please?

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information to say for sure -- we need to see the body of `fivepoint_helper` and *all* the changes you made between the mex version and the standalone version (the change you showed cannot possibly have been the complete change).  However, I have a guess: Matlab, like Fortran, indexes matrices in column-major ("backward") order.  C indexes matrices in row-major ("correct") order.  You may therefore need to interchange the indices on every matrix element lookup.

Comment: I just edited my question and added a part of the mex file (the file is very long and exceeds the number of characters allowed)

Comment: @zwol I agree with you. In fact, I stole your answer accidentally as I immediately jumped on this myself. :). This is really common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB is column-major, while C is generally row-major (so your input to `fivepoint_helper` likely has row-major data organization).  Assuming `EE` is 9 rows by 4 columns you have,

```
e27 = EE[2*9 + 7 ]; // row 7, column 2 ?
```

where 9 is the number of rows, so this looks OK, but **only for column-major inputs**.  If you are using this to read in row-major data in the C only (non-MEX) version, then that will be wrong.

For a fix, you could change all of these equations to deal with row-major input, and to make the MEX version work, transpose the input.  That's a quick fix, but you could also add a transpose inside the MEX file version.

Comment: E is 9x4, so column major will use the number of rows `(row + column*rows)` while row major will use the number of columns `(column + row*columns)`  Definitely wrong for both expressions to contain `*9` (the number of rows)

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right, of course.  That's what happens when I try to answer on my phone.  I'm updating with a better example element.

Comment: @BenVoigt Now that I look again on a computer screen :), there is nothing wrong with getting row 7, col 2 via `[2*9 + 7]`, where 9 is the number of rows.  But that's only good for the MATLAB version.  I'm guessing he calls `fivepoint_helper` with a row-major version of the matrix `EE`.

Comment: @Daphnée as a test just try to transpose the input from MATLAB.  The answer may be wrong, but it will indicate why the discrepancy exists

Comment: @chappjc I finally got a correct result. For EE I swaped row and column indices and used a row major indexing for example: `e27=EE[2*9+7]`is changed to `e27=[7*4+9]`I used also a row major indexing for the output A for example `A[1 + 10*6]`become `A[1*20+6]`..Thank you for your help